# Helm chart lint to find resources missing namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, lint, helm3

I have a helm chart where some of the namespaced resources are missing namespace, which leads to their installation in default namespace. Is there a way to find all such namespaced resources, where namespace is missing, without actually installing.

Comment: What is the command that you are running, what is the exact error? Did you write the chart and are asking for help fixing it? Could you post more information please

Comment: Most of the charts are written to be installed in any namespace that we provide during install time (`helm install`). Try using `--namespace <your-namespace-name>` arguments when execute the `helm install`, so the resources will be deployed to the desired namespace and not to default namespace.
You can also create a namespace when running `helm install`. Please read the official documentation [here](https://helm.sh/docs/faq/changes_since_helm2/#automatically-creating-namespaces).

Comment: I am not looking to install. just want to know the namespaces before hand